For any positive integer $n\geq5$, there is at least one integer $m>n$ such that $ \pi\left(nm\right)=n+m $
Conjecture:
For any positive integer $n\geq5$, there is at least one integer $m>n$ such that $ \pi\left(nm\right)=n+m $, where $\pi\left(x\right)$ is the prime counting function.
Examples:
$$ \pi(5\times9)=5+9=14  $$
$$ \pi(6\times7)=6+7=13  $$
$$ \pi(7\times368)=7+368=375  $$
$$ \pi(8\times998)=8+998=1006  $$
$$ \pi(9\times2551)=9+2551=2560  $$

I'm looking for either a proof of the conjecture, or at least an heuristic argument for big enough $n$.
Computations:
The nbr column denotes the number of solutions, while the min and max columns represent the first and last solutions.



n
nbr
min
max




1
0




2
0




3
0




4
0




5
22
9
41


6
9
7
148


7
14
368
409


8
1
998
998


9
12
2551
2597


10
6
6331
6424


11
7
15866
15889


12
25
39860
39970


13
20
100135
100192


14
9
251616
251637


15
19
636787
637063


16
2
1617099
1617110


17
13
4124188
4124272


18
9
10553076
10553278


19
13
27066256
27066824


20
28
69709243
69709557


21
17
179992154
179992524


22
50
465769460
465769748


23
13
1208198239
1208198402


24
43
3140421185
3140421406


25
20
8179001679
8179001739


26
8
21338684878
21338685037


27
68
55762147707
55762148901


28
1
145935688930
145935688930


29
95
382465571795
382465572544



Graph:
Here is a graph of $\pi(nm)-(n+m)$ for $n=12$:

And here is the same graph, but zoomed on the interval where it crosses the $0$ axis:

In this example, $n=12$, the line touches $25$ times the $0$ axis, and we can expect that as $n$ gets bigger, the interval in which the line is close to $0$ will also become larger.

That's a very small search range...I wouldn't have a lot of confidence in that.

Given $n$ the line $y=nx$ it is a "very good curve" to search suitable $m$ (not sure obviously!).

Considering the exponential growing smallest solution (I guess you used the prime number theorem to find them rather than applying brute force) , it will be difficult to extend the table much further.

@Peter,
if you look at the graph I added, you can see that it was not very difficult to find the precise interval to calculate, but you are completely right, to extend the table to say n=40, you would need to know the value of the function well beyond what is known to date...

The conjecture is true, basically because every time we increment $m$, the integer-valued function $f_n(m) = \pi(mn)-(m+n)$ might increase by a lot but can only decrease by $1$.
More precisely, note that $f_n(n) = \pi(n^2)-2n>0$ for $n\ge7$, while $\lim_{m\to\infty} f_n(m) = -\infty$ (both of these statements can be justified using standard inequalities for $\pi(x)$). That means that it is well defined to consider $k$, the largest integer greater than $n$ for which $f_n(k)>0$. But then
$$
0 \ge f_n(k+1) = \pi(m(k+1))-(m+k+1) \ge \pi(m(k+1))-(m+k+1) = f_n(k) - 1 \ge 0,
$$
which forces $f_n(k+1) = 0$ and thus $\pi(n(k+1)) = k+1+n$.
